# Deserialize a dynamic property in an ASP.net web-api

Tags: c#, mongodb, post, asp.net-web-api

I have an `element` class that contains an`options` property, the option class can in turn change its properties for example could have these 2

```
Element1 = {
    "Id": "1",
    "Options": {
        "Printable": "true",
        "StackOverflow": "great"
    }
}

Element2 = {
    "Id": "2",
    "Options": {
        "Question": "awsome",
        "PropertyDiferent": "empty"
    }
}
```

On the web api I have a method like this:

```
Public object Post ([FromBody] Element element)
{
    SaveToMongo (element);
}
```

The element class:

```
Public class Element
{
    Public dynamic options {get; set; }
    Public string id {get; set; }
}
```

When I pick up the Element from Mongo I have no problems. But when I send it using the post method of the Api web, it does not deserialize itself, in an expando object as it does since Mongo. How could I get similar behavior at both ends?

Edit: I tried to change options from dynamic to a newtonsoft  JObject, but it didn't work. Also now the options get saved, but they generate a father that I don't want.

```
"options" : {
            "_t" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed", 
            "_v" : {
                "padding" : {
                    "_t" : "JArray", 
                    "_v" : [
                        {
                            "_t" : "JValue", 
                            "_v" : [

                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_t" : "JValue", 
                            "_v" : [

                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_t" : "JValue", 
                            "_v" : [

                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_t" : "JValue", 
                            "_v" : [

                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "image" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue", 
                    "_v" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "alt" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue", 
                    "_v" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "url" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue", 
                    "_v" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "width" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue", 
                    "_v" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "backgroundColor" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue", 
                    "_v" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "text" : {
                    "_t" : "JValue", 
                    "_v" : [

                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

there are more properties because I extracted the example directly from mongo.

Comment: Can you use JObject from Newtonsoft.Json instead of dynamic?

Comment: @PedroDrewanz I'm going to try it. as my few aproaches these days have been a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, make the `ajax` call from javascript pass the JSON as a string, otherwise the dynamic property options are not populated.

```
Element.options = element.options.toString ();
```

So I have a JSON string that although it is stored in the mongo I can recover it without being modified. But to be able to return it in the Api I have to deserialize it before the deserialization done by the controller itself.

```
Element.options = JObject.Parse (element.options);
```

It is an uncool system, with a few disadvantages, as it does not allow the treatment of options in mongo. But it has been the only way in which I have managed that the passage by the mongo did not modify the object.